# Running program every 2 minutes with crontab

Tags: crontab

What does

```
2 * * * *
```

means in crontab context?

I want to run my program every 2 minutes; is that what 2 * * * * means?

Answer (score 111):

Not quite; that means every 2nd minute of the hour (i.e., 6:02, 7:02, 8:02, etc.). To make it every 2 minutes, use `*/2` in the first entry:

```
*/2 * * * * my-script.sh
```

You can read more about the crontab syntax and available options **[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#crontab_syntax)** at Wikipedia. **[Ubuntu's got a good overview too](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)**.